# encoding' is an unexpected token. the expected token is '?>' when reading XML data into DataSet

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting below runtime error when my xml file data is reading into DataSet using Readxml.

"encoding' is an unexpected token. the expected token is '?>'"

My C# code is:

```
XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("WH7_Inventory.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());            
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
```

My xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute value for `standalone` is incorrect. It should be either `yes` or `no`.

See the [Standalone Document Declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-rmd)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

You will probably still get an error though assuming this is all you have in your XML doc as you have no root element.

Comment: Sorry about the downvotes. The user responsible has been warned, and the script should reverse all of these tonight. If they aren't gone by tomorrow, let me know and I'll ping the community team.